# Using Senz3d with depthimage_to_laserscan

Tags: ros, camera-depth-points, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm using Senz3d to get depthimage data, and I would like to use this depthimage data with package depthimage_to_laserscan. But when I run this data with depthimage_to_laserscan package, it showed the warning message below:

[ WARN] [1407311794.272714061]: [image_transport] Topics '/softkinetic_camera/depth_registered/image' and '/softkinetic_camera/depth_registered/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
Image messages received: 33
CameraInfo messages received: 0
Synchronized pairs: 0

I think I have to publish '/softkinetic_camera/depth_registered/camera_info', but I don't have any experienced with this. So, anyone can help me?

Thanks,
Duong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189136/using-senz3d-with-depthimage_to_laserscan/) by [buihaduong](https://answers.ros.org/users/19453/buihaduong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your camera driver isn't publishing CameraInfo messages for the depth image properly.

The driver probably needs to be updated to support maintaining and publishing CameraInfo. The [camera_info_manager](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_info_manager) library makes this easier.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buihaduong](https://answers.ros.org/users/19453/buihaduong/) on 2014-08-06**:
Hi ahendrix,

Thank for your answer. Do you have any guides or tutorials to work with camera_info_manager and CameraInfo ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-07**:
Not really. The only tutorial available in the camera_info_manager package just links to the source code the camera1394 driver: http://wiki.ros.org/camera_info_manager/Tutorials/UsingCameraInfoManagerInCameraDriver%28C%2B%2B%29

**Comment by [buihaduong](https://answers.ros.org/users/19453/buihaduong/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thank ahendrix, I'm trying to use camera_info_manager. I will post the solution when success.

**Comment by [buihaduong](https://answers.ros.org/users/19453/buihaduong/) on 2014-08-07**:
Hi @ahendrix, do you have experienced with following error:
Could not convert depth image to laserscan: scan_height ( 1 pixels) is too large for the image height.?